# AngularJS/HTML/Bootstrap element for dynamic search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm looking for element for showing search results. My requirement is initially a textbox will be displayed. when user start typing in that, search results will be displayed in list format.

I thought of combo-box with search field. But I feel 2 ugly things with that.

1. down arrow
2. All items will be listed there.

If there is any new and advanced element which I can use, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

select2 and his angular directive should help you :)

check : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select
and   : https://select2.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try http://www.listjs.com/

It serves me well for most purposes and is simple to use. It also supports more advance methods of search through your list such as Fuzzy Search.